# Ascending Order for 2-D Array, Not working..?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I am trying to output my `2D` array into an Ascending order.

I have already output it into the order which the user put in. But can not get it to print to Ascending Order.

- Could anybody possibly help with this or know a solution? My code is below for any question regarding code.

  `int main() {
      /* 2D array declaration and size of each Array in the Programme*/
      int Array[2][3];
      printf ("***** Bubble Sort Assessment 2 ***** \n");
      /*Counter variables for the loop*/
      int i, j;
      for(i=0; i<2; i++)
      {
          for(j=0; j<3; j++)
          {
              printf("Enter numeric values for each Array [%d][%d]: \n", i, j);
              scanf("%d", &Array[i][j]);
          }
      }
      /*Displaying array elements*/
      printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
      for(i=0; i<2; i++)
      {
          for(j=0; j<3; j++)
          {
              printf("%d " , Array[i][j]);
              if(j==2)
              {
                  printf("\n");
              }
          }
      }
      printf("\n\nAscending : ");
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
          printf(" %d ", a[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {
              if (a[j] < a[i])
              {
                  int tmp = a[i];
                  a[i] = a[j];
                  a[j] = tmp;
              }
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }`

Comment: Does this code get compiled? You didn’t define ‘’’a’’’ array.

Answer (score 0):

First Use bubble sort algorithm

```
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<size; ++j)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[j]))
        {
            int temp=a[i];
            a[i]=array[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then print your array in an ascending order.

Try to apply your own way, you can use some features of arrays like arrays contiguity.

```
int *ptr=a;
```

same with

```
*(ptr+i), *(ptr+j)
```

Comment: Please note that `int Array[2][3]` is 2D array.  You are sorting 1D `a` what is the correlation?

Comment: int *ptr=arr 
...........
*(ptr+i)
..............
*(ptr+j)
............
He is doing an assignment, I just mentioned the main idea.
he can use contiguous arrays, or even apply the algorithm in his own way.

Answer (score 0):

To use a simple one dimensional `bubble sort algorithm` to sort `2D` array you have to add another loop taking care of the rows.

In your case:

```
for(k =0; k< 2; k++) {
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < 3; ++j) {
           if (a[k][i] > a[k][j])  {
               int swap = a[k][i];
               a[k][i] = a[k][j];
               a[k][j] = swap;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    /* 2D array declaration and size of each Array in the Programme*/
    int a[2][3];
    printf ("***** Bubble Sort Assessment 2 ***** \n");
    /*Counter variables for the loop*/
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter numeric values for each Array [%d][%d]: \n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    /*Displaying array elements*/
    printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d " , a[i][j]);
            if(j==2)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    // SORT: 
    for( k = 0; k< 2; k++) {
       for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for ( j = i+1; j < 3; ++j) {
               if (a[k][i] > a[k][j])  {
                   int swap = a[k][i];
                   a[k][i] = a[k][j];
                   a[k][j] = swap;
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    printf("\n\nAscending : ");
    printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d " , a[i][j]);
            if(j==2)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
***** Bubble Sort Assessment 2 *****                                                                                                           
Enter numeric values for each Array [0][0]:                                                                                                    
1                                                                                                                                              
Enter numeric values for each Array [0][1]:                                                                                                    
0                                                                                                                                              
Enter numeric values for each Array [0][2]:                                                                                                    
2                                                                                                                                              
Enter numeric values for each Array [1][0]:                                                                                                    
5                                                                                                                                              
Enter numeric values for each Array [1][1]:                                                                                                    
4                                                                                                                                              
Enter numeric values for each Array [1][2]:                                                                                                    
3                                                                                                                                              

 The 2-D Array contains :                                                                                                                      
1 0 2                                                                                                                                          
5 4 3                                                                                                                                          


Ascending :                                                                                                                                    
 The 2-D Array contains :                                                                                                                      
0 1 2                                                                                                                                          
3 4 5
```

Comment: Hey man, I am just reading over it and it really does make sense, i understand how the ascending order works. 
I am getting an error an called "'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode"
Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Define the variable `i,j,k` at the start of the `main` together with the other variables.`C89` does not allow  `int i` to be declared  inside the `loop`. I have updated the example for `C89` compiler. If you use `gcc` you can compile for `C99` mode by `gcc -std=c99`

Comment: I only just noticed that just as i posted the Comment.. man i couldn't think straight. Cheers bud!

Comment: @Morph Cheers! If you like my post you can accept my answer. Thanks!